# What makes the following code print false?

Tags: java, puzzle

```
public class Guess {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        <sometype> x = <somevalue>;
        System.out.println(x == x);
    }
}
```

i have to change sometype and somevalue so that it returns false? is it possible?

Comment: "x = ;" will not compile

Comment: Is it homework? Please format your code correctly.

Comment: give the concrete code, so that we see what <sometype> is

Comment: I think the question is, for which `someType`/`someValue` will `x == x` be false? So this is as concrete as it gets.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One:

```
float x = Float.NaN;
```

Two:

```
double x = 0.0/0.0;
```

Why?

As mentioned here already, `NaN` is never equal to another `NaN`  - see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html

---

So why this is not returning false?

```
Float x = Float.NaN;
```

The answer is that here, instead of a primitive assignment, there is a reference assignment. And there is a little auto boxing in the background. This is equal to:

```
Float x = new Float(Float.NaN);
```

Which is equal to:

```
Float x = new Float(0.0f / 0.0f);
```

Here x is a reference to a Float object, and the == operator tests reference equality, not value.

To see this returning false as well, the test should have been:

```
x.doubleValue()==x.doubleValue();
```

Which indeed returns false

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, you need to use:

```
// Edited for primitives :)
float x = Float.NaN;
// or
double x = Double.NaN;
```

This is because NaN is a special case that is not equal to itself.

From the JLS (4.2.3):

> NaN is unordered, so the numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= return false if either or both operands are NaN (§15.20.1). The equality operator == returns false if either operand is NaN, and the inequality operator != returns true if either operand is NaN (§15.21.1). In particular, x!=x is true if and only if x is NaN, and (x=y) will be false if x or y is NaN.

Comment: it return true. did you verify?

Comment: @gurukulki: He accidently wrote Float x and Double x. It probabl needs to be the primitives to avoid object identity comparison.

Comment: Yep Float x = Float.NaN prints true, float x = Float.NaN prints false

Answer (score 0):

<s>I can't think of any `someType` and `someValue` for which you could get `x == x` to come up false, sorry.</s>

---

**Update**

Oh... yes, I think NAN is equal to nothing, even itself. So...

`double` and `Double.NaN` (or so).

Answer (score 0):

This will print false:

```
!(x == x)
```

Other then that, it will only print false if you use NaN

```
float x = float.NaN;
Console.WriteLine(x == x);
```